# Front right 'squeals' when turning

Tags: brakes, steering, noise

Hi I have an incredibly frustrating noise coming from the front right of the car. It only occurred after replacing pads and rotors. It occurs when turning left (weight on right) and occasionally going straight. Seems to get worse the hotter it gets (ie. Hot weather is worse, or longer drives gets worse). Putting brakes on seems to get rid of it or at least suppress it. Much more noticeable at higher speeds.

Here is a video for a more accurate description. (Starts midway in).
http://youtu.be/nX1TOWUcits
Things I've tried:

- reseat brake pads ensuring wear tabs are not scraping rotor.
- bend back rotor sheet metal 'guard'.
- grease caliper slides and clean.
- put old brake pads back in.
- replace front hub (rule out wheel bearing)
- replace front right caliper and brake lines (and obviously bleed).

Not sure what else to do, this is driving me insane. I did admit defeat and take it to a mechanic just for a look over, he said everything seems fine and recommended changing the caliper, which I did...

Apart from the noise the brakes perform exceptional, nice pedal, no shudder.

Thank you for reading look forward to suggestions...

Comment: **Are you sure the tire isn't rubbing on something during the turn?** Yes, that is a truly annoying sound! Sounds like you've done everything possible to get it right, though.

Comment: Yep tires definitely not rubbing. I have another desperate theory that I'd like to test: When the brakes heat up the pads expand? And push the calipers out a small amount, this small change is enough to make sure the caliper hit the inner rim. Tommorow I shall check the caliper clearance and if it is indeed miniscule I shall swap a spare rim on and observe.

Comment: I had a very similar situation with my motorcycle, a squealing sound when i ride it. But no sound stops when i apply breaks. This friend of mine told me to push the bike backwards so that the disk rotates in reverse direction inside the break pads, and if there's anything stuck in-between it gets removed. Now being more experienced rider, needless to say, i made so much fun of him and even used a few not-so-friendly words at him. And then he did it for me and believe me, it worked. A few meters backwards and the sound just stopped!! Dont ask why. I really have no idea. It just magically did.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to reply on mobile...anyway you mean drive in reverse and brake? If so I've definitely done this as I've been driving the car in this condition for over a week now :(

Comment: If there was a clearance issue, it wouldn't be there when you put the old brakes back on. Also, it should be *very* easy to see a clearance issue as to where it's rubbing on the rim in the first place. Just thinking about it more, you may need to look closer at your bushings in the rest of your suspension. Take a look at upper/lower ball joints (if so equipped), lower A-frame bushings, shock/strut mount bushing, etc. If these areas are worn, it could allow some type of rub which causes the harmonics you are hearing. Just thinking out loud at this point.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue or have you resolved it?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you find a solution by chance? Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Could be bearing play, but since you checked that, check the slide pins of the caliper. Maybe even crappy pads or brake hardware.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site.  Check this out.  It's a good overview.  http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour   This is a QA site.  Works different than a forum.   We need to get you some rep so you can leave comments on questions.   If you dig around in here you can see how it's different than a forum.   Thanks for the contributions and check out that link.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Could be an alignment issue putting the rotors in a constant bind and not allowing enough relief when the brakes are at rest.